# Using Write() to write to a pipe is always returning 0

Tags: c, pipe, parent-child

I'm trying to have two processes write to each other in the following way:
 1. Parent writes to Child
 2. Child Receives message from Parent
 3. Child writes to Parent
 4. Parent receives message from Child

I don't understand why when I try to send the letter "A" it the write function always returns zero. Does anyone know why? I looked at the man page and it just says it's return 0 bytes but "A" is a char which should be one byte?

```
int main()
{
    int fdP[2]; //used for child to contact parent 
    int fdC[2]; //used by parent to contact child
    int nBytes;
    char readBuffer[2];
    char writeBuffer[2];

    pipe(fdP); //Child >> Parent
    pipe(fdC); //Parent >> Child

    pid_t  pid;
    pid = fork();
    if( pid < 0)
    {
        perror("There was an error during the fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    //two processes running here
    if (pid == 0) //child process
    {   
        close(fdP[0]);
        close(fdC[1]);
        while (nBytes != 0) //when nbytes is nonzero it received a message
        {
            nBytes = read(fdP[0], readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer));
        }
        printf("Child received: %s\n", readBuffer);

        write(fdP[1], "B", sizeof(readBuffer));
        exit(0);
    }
    else //parent process
    {
        close(fdC[1]);
        close(fdP[0]);

        while(write(fdC[1], "A", sizeof("A")) != 0) //THIS ALWAYS RETURNS ZERO
        {
            printf("%s\n", "I'M STUCK HERE");
        }

        while (nBytes != 0) //when nbytes is nonzero it received a message
        {
            nBytes = read(fdC[0], readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer));
        }
        printf("Parent received: %s\n", readBuffer);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    printf("%s\n", "finished");
}
```

Comment: `close(fdC[1]);`, 2 lines later `write(fdC[1],...` ... yeah, can't figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues:

- You use nBytes before you initialize it. This is undefined behavior.
- `sizeof("A")` is wrong. That gives the size of a `const char*`, not the actual size of the string.
- Your logic of testing the read()s and write()s with 0s is backwards. (Actually, for this toy program, you can remove the loops and nBytes variables completely, and just do each read() and write() once.)

Also, you mix up your file descriptors. Assuming your comments on them are right, here's the details:

- The child process should read from fdC[0], not fdP[0].
- The parent process closes the opposite file descriptors from the ones that it's supposed to.
- The parent process should read from fdP[0], not fdC[0].

When I fix all of the above, your code appears to do what you want. Here's what I ended up with:

```
int main()
{
    int fdP[2]; //used for child to contact parent 
    int fdC[2]; //used by parent to contact child
    char readBuffer[2];

    pipe(fdP); //Child >> Parent
    pipe(fdC); //Parent >> Child

    pid_t  pid;
    pid = fork();
    if( pid < 0)
    {
        perror("There was an error during the fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    //two processes running here
    if (pid == 0) //child process
    {   
        close(fdP[0]);
        close(fdC[1]);
        read(fdC[0], readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer));
        printf("Child received: %s\n", readBuffer);
        write(fdP[1], "B", 2);
        exit(0);
    }
    else //parent process
    {
        close(fdC[0]);
        close(fdP[1]);
        write(fdC[1], "A", 2);
        read(fdP[0], readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer));
        printf("Parent received: %s\n", readBuffer);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    printf("%s\n", "finished");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the child you are closing the side of the pipe you then try to read from.  In the parent you close the side of the pipe you then try to write to.

Also, the while loops are not checking for the right size.

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    int fdChildtoParent[2]; //used for child to contact parent
    int fdParentToChild[2]; //used by parent to contact child
    int nBytes;
    char childInbox[1];
    char parentInbox[1];

    pipe(fdChildtoParent); //Child >> Parent
    pipe(fdParentToChild); //Parent >> Child

    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0)
    {
        perror("There was an error during the fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    //two processes running here
    if(pid == 0) //child process
    {
        close(fdChildtoParent[0]);
        close(fdParentToChild[1]);

        read(fdParentToChild[0], childInbox, sizeof(childInbox));

        printf("Child received: %s\n", childInbox);

        write(fdChildtoParent[1], "B", sizeof("B"));

        exit(0);
    }
    else //parent process
    {
        close(fdParentToChild[0]);
        close(fdChildtoParent[1]);

        write(fdParentToChild[1], "A", sizeof("A"));

        read(fdChildtoParent[0], parentInbox, sizeof(parentInbox));

        printf("Parent received: %s\n", parentInbox);

        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your code isn't valid. The loop that copies bytes should use the read count in the write, and the code that sends "A" is actually sending two bytes, not one, as sizeof "A" includes the trailing null.
- Your comment 'when nbytes is nonzero it received a message' isn't correct either. If it is *positive* it received a message of that length, otherwise there was an error that you need to print, using `perror()` for example, and then you will almost certainly need to close the socket.
- You are ignoring every read except the last one that does return zero, so you're losing data.

The correct way to read is as follows:

```
while ((count = read(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0)
{
    // do something with buffer[0..count], for example write(fd2, buffer, count);
}
if (count == 0)
    ; // end of stream
else
{
    // count < 0
    perror("read");
}
```